# How to assign ports on the same switch to different sub-nets?

Tags: networking, router, switch, subnet, vlan

I am new in networking and just finished my graduate work.

I read a lot about networking, sub-nets, classes, and VLANs, and I want to clear some confusion.  Where I'm stuck is the practical assignment of  different classes or sub-nets  on the same switch.

For example I have a 24-port switch and I want to assign VLAN1 to 12 ports and VLAN2 to the remaining.

1. How should I configure or setup the router for that purpose?
2. How does the switch know that these ports are assigned to VLAN1 or VLAN2?

Answer (score 1):

When you configure **VLAN ID** to a **switchport**, each **switchport** will have the VLAN tag number in its interface configuration.

Every time when the packet traverse this VLAN tagged interface, ***packet will be tagged / untagged as per the flow***.

All the **VLAN** and **switchport** mapping table will be **saved on the running-config** of the switch.

**Configuration:**

```
Switch# configure terminal
Enter configuration commands, one per line. End with CNTL/Z.
Switch(config)# interface fastethernet0/2
Switch(config-if)# switchport mode trunk
Switch(config-if)# switchport trunk native vlan 33
Switch(config-if)# end
```